# Twisted deferToThread addCallback call

Tags: python, twisted

```
from __future__ import print_function
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads
import time

def printResult(x):
    def _callback(response):
        print('Number %s' %x)
        print('Result %s' % response)        
        print('--------------------------')
    return _callback


def doLongCalculation(z):
    s = 0
    for i in xrange(z):
        s += i
    return s

for i in xrange(100000):
    d = threads.deferToThread(doLongCalculation, z=i)
    d.addCallback(printResult(i))

reactor.run()
```

Can you please highlight the way `addCallback(printResult(i))` is called?

I know as per doc it should be `addCallback(printResult, i)` and printResult should be defined as below

```
def printResult(response, x):    
    print('Number %s' %x)
    print('Result %s' % response)        
    print('--------------------------')
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
for i in xrange(100000):
    d = threads.deferToThread(doLongCalculation, z=i)
    d.addCallback(printResult(i))
```

is the same as:

```
for i in xrange(100000):
    d = threads.deferToThread(doLongCalculation, z=i)
    _callback = printResult(i)
    d.addCallback(_callback)
```

`_callback` is a closure function defined in *and* returned by `printResult`, that is, `_callback` may reference variables defined inside `printResult`. In this case there is a reference to `i` passed to `printResult(i)`, since you are printing `x` (x = i here) in `_callback`.
When the Deferred `d` is fired (by calling `d.callback(result)`) Twisted will begin resolving the callback chain. `_callback` is the first, then `_callback(result)` will be called.
Since numbers are immutable, the variable `x` defined in `printResult` as an argument will not change, we can have a more clear view of how closure functions works. If I call `printResult(5)`, `x` = **5**, I will have a **new** closure function defined as:

```python
def _callback(response):
    print('Number %s' % 5) # replaced x by 5
    print('Result %s' % response)        
    print('--------------------------')
return _callback
```

Note that substitution does not happens in real code, if the object referenced by `x` changes (i.e it's mutable), the first `print` in `_callback` will change too.

Taking `printResult(response, x)`, the above example about closure functions will be equivalent to:

```
d.addCallback(printResult, 5)
```

And as you know, twisted will call that this way `printResult(result, 5)`